# how to solve: seting locale translation from laravel middleware not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I am configuring a multilanguage app. The user is visiting the app as a guest (I wonder if this is related).

My default language in config/app.php is pt-BR. I created a database table called languages, where I save the languages available for the app.

Languages model

```php
Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('iso2');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('native');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I have a dropdown in the navigation bar where the user can select the language. Then, when the page loads, I get the locale from the session to display as the desired locale/language.

```php
<x-dropdown align="right" width="48">
    <x-slot name="trigger">
        <button >
            <div class="flex">
                <x-flag :name="app()->getLocale()" />
            </div>

            <div class="ml-1">
                svg for down array
            </div>
        </button>
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="content">
        @foreach ($languages as $lang)
            <x-dropdown-link :href="route('language', $lang->iso2)" >
                <x-flag :name="$lang->iso2" />
                <span class="ml-2">{{ $lang->native }}</span>
            </x-dropdown-link>
        @endforeach
    </x-slot>
</x-dropdown>
```

Web route for setting the language:

```php
Route::get('lang/{language:iso2}', [LocalizationController::class, 'index'])->name('language');
```

When the user select the language, a request is sent to this controller.

LocalizationController.php

```php
public function index(Language $language)
{
    session()->put('locale', $language->iso2);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

And I defined this middleware: App\Http\Middleware\Localization:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class Localization
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('locale')) {
            Carbon::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
            App::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I also registered the middleware in kernel.php:

```php
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
        ...
    ];
```

But when I select a locale other than pt-BR, nothing happens. The locale from the session changes, but when I dd on middleware like:

```php
dump("Locale session value in localization middleware: ",session()->get('locale') );
```

The locale is null, but if I print session()->get('locale') in the view, the locale is the one that I selected in the dropdown, but the app locale is still pt-br. I don't understand why this is happening. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: I don't how u checked that, but use ``info()`` instead of ``dd()`` because session is persisted after application tear down, and see what's the value in log file

Comment: Jessica make sure you have pt_BR instead of pt-BR. Aconteceu comigo

Answer (score 0):

You come up with some crutches!

Why are you doing some kind of reverse redirect to the same page when choosing a language on the site? In your dropdownlist for each language, a link to the page on which you are located should be generated, taking into account the locale! No redirects!

Why are you saving languages to a database? On Your website will use a thousand languages? Or will there be a new language version of the site every day? Why else load the application with unnecessary queries to the database to get a list of languages? If you need to store lang in the database, then these should be translations!

For localization in **config/app** You must have one default locale in the *locale* cell.

Next, you can add an additional cell to this configuration file, for example, *locales*, where you can set all the languages ​​that you want to use on the site, for example, like this:

```
// ....

    'locales' => ['ru', 'en'],

// ....
```

Create a simple service. Register it in cell *providers* in **config/app**:

```
php artisan make:provider App\Services\Localization\LocalizationServiceProvider
```

In the service write the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Localization;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

/**
 * Class LocalizationServiceProvider
 *
 * @package App\Services\Localization
 */
class LocalizationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('Localization', function () {
            return new Localization;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

For convenience, we create a facade for the created service provider:

```
<?php


namespace App\Services\Localization;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

/**
 * Class LocalizationService
 *
 * @package App\Services\Localization
 */
class LocalizationService extends Facade
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getFacadeAccessor(): string
    {
        return 'Localization';
    }
}
```

And add a additional class Localization, where we create one simple method:

```
<?php


namespace App\Services\Localization;

/**
 * Class Localization
 * 
 * @package App\Services\Localization
 */
class Localization
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function locale(): string
    {
        $locale = request()->segment(1);
        if($locale && \in_array($locale, config('app.locales'))) {
            \App::setLocale($locale);
            return $locale;
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

Then for the routes you set a group something like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LocalizationService::locale()], 'middleware' => [/*...*/]], function () {
    // YOUR routes here ....
});
```

**Checked on Laravel v9.48. Working 100%!**